# logmein-hamachi - cannot login on Linux VM

Tags: linux, vpn

I am using a VirtualBox VM with hamachi-logmein to access my home box from other places. Lately I decided to switch from Windows 8.1 VM to Linux VM, and this caused one problem:

The logmein-hamachi works in some networks, while it doesn't in others. Under Windows it did and still does. Of course, on the Linux VM I did all the necessary steps (login,

I tried this under CentOS, Debian and Ubuntu, and on all three I can't successfully execute 'sudo hamachi login':

```
ushuru@hamak-linux:~$ sudo hamachi login
Logging in ..
```

And it just stays like that indefinitely (waited for an hour before I aborted it).